# Setting height on TR is different from height on TD. Why?

Tags: html, html-table, height, tr

I don't understand the different behavior between these two pieces of HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><body>
<TABLE style='border:1px solid black'>
<TR>
    <TD style='height:100px'><div style='width:100px;height:100%;background-color:#ccc'></div></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</body></html>
```

JFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ceyq6n10/

and

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><body>
<TABLE style='border:1px solid black'>
<TR style='height:100px'>
    <TD><div style='width:100px;height:100%;background-color:#ccc'></div></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</body></html>
```

JFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hmjvu5gf/

In the first example, the DIV is vertically expanded to 100% of the TD height. In the second one, even if the TD has the right vertical size, the DIV has height 0.

Could you please explain me why? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `height: 100%` for `<div>`, but didn't specify height to the parent `<td>`. 
If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the used height is calculated as if 'auto' was specified.

[css spec about height calculation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#propdef-height)

So when you use % for setting heights or widths, always set the widths/heights of parent elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

By resizing the cells, we can control the row height.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply such styling rules to the containers that hold actual content inside like text or other html. In this case, you td is actual container for content.

For tr tag, you can only put th or td inside a tr, and not the actual content. Style for screen space applies on tags which are actual content containers (like td, th), or actually themselves can grab screen space. tr is more of row de-marker.
You can apply things like background-color to tr, and it will work for td. Apply screen space rule to more specific content container.